# React Native: "tintColor" not working for Image on iOS 15

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I have some code like this throughout my app:

```
<Image
  style={{width: 50, height: 50, tintColor: 'yellow'}}
  source={fabicon}
/>
```

This is working fine on Android and on iOS <15. However, the `tintColor` is not applied to any of my icons on iOS 15.

I am on React Native version 0.62.2.

Can anyone let me know how I can apply tint color to images on iOS 15 (and above)? If I can't, do I make separate images for every color I want an image to be? I could use SVGs, but that also is not an option for every scenario in my app.

Comment: that sounds weird indeed. You should open an issue on react-native's github. Meanwhile you will have to find an alternative, maybe create the different colored images in advance, use icons or SVGs as you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised this issue on React Native's repo:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32251

They released a new RN version 0.66.0 on 2nd October, 2021. I have confirmed that `tintColor` works on this new version and closed this issue.

For anyone below RN 66 who has this issue with Image `tintColor`, you can upgrade to RN 66 for `tintColor` to work. If upgrading is not an option now, you can use [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) until you can upgrade. Alternatively, you can use different-colored versions of your images or SVGs as suits your needs. If your tinted images are mostly icons, you can also use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons).